# Postgresq-9.2 falha em conexão no Unix Domain Socket

Tags: postgresql

Configurei o banco postgresql-9.2 em meu Ubuntu 14.04 e o mesmo apresenta o seguinte erro na hora de comunicação com o banco

> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Estou usando ele para uma aplicação em Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, abra o terminal e rode o seguinte comando:

```
ps auxw | grep postgres
```

Caso não haja nenhum processo com o nome postgres, então o banco não está rodando. Se este for o seu caso, insira o seguinte comando no seu terminal:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Casp esteja rodando, verifique as permissões do diretório `/var/run/postgresql/`, veja se o usuário postgres tem permissão de leitura/escrita. Se não tiver esta permissão, use o seguinte comando:

```
sudo chown postgres /var/run/postgresql/
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar, localize e verifique seu arquivo postgres.conf, procure pela linha que define o socket e edite esta linha com o caminho `/var/run/postgresql`

Comment: Ainda não tive sucesso. Apresenta o mesmo erro. Por fim adicionei o caminho no postgres.conf da seguinte forma:

unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'

Comment: @ygorbr, chegaste a reiniciar o postgre depois da edição do postgres.conf ?

Comment: Resolvi o problema desinstalando todo pacote do postgres e instalando novamente. Obrigado pela ajuda Renato.